# How can I completely disable Clipboard History/Cycling in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clipboard

I have clipboard problems every day, just from doing simple cut, copy and paste operations. The clipboard in Visual Studio fails half the time for me, and it drives me insane.

Is there any way to completely turn off the Clipboard History/Cycling functionality? I just want simple reliable copy and paste.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure it out?